# How to change navbar contents of the User Change page in Django admin?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on Django.And I wanted to change the navbar content in the User Change Page in the Django admin as marked with red color in the pic :

[image]

And my admin file is :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

It is same as the default Django user model name so only I want to change it.
So it can be changed or is it permanent??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be changed and for that you dont need to make any changes to your admin file but instead in the models.py file.In the models.py file you have to add a `Meta` class to your user model and define `verbose_name` in it like this:

```
    class Meta:
        verbose_name="Type here your desired name instead of name users"
```

And then that navbar content will be changed as you wished.